# Java interpreta UTF-8 como unicode aunque le especifique una codificacion UTF-8

Tags: php, java, crud, utf-8, gson

Sobre lo que trata mi código es una conexión y envió de información a una base de datos, en este caso cree un `CRUD` para facilitar las cosas, además ese era uno de los requerimientos...

Por ahora mi `CRUD` funciona correctamente, no hay ningún problema, excepto en el caso de que intente usar tildes para enviar informacion a un archivo `.php`, tengo 4 archivos basicos los cuales representan el `CRUD`:

- create.php
- update.php
- read.php
- delete.php

Si bien por el momento sus nombres son bastante irrelevantes, me desconcierta el hecho de que haga lo que haga **en el backend** específicamente en el archivo **update.php**, los datos que obtengo no se encuentran en formato `UTF-8`, al parecer llegan como `unicode + UTF-8` u otro formato, haga lo que haga...

Sospecho que se trata de lo que uso para encodificar los parametros de la `URL`, uso `URLEncoder`.

Segun el archivo **update.php**, al enviar los parametros, uno de ellos es recibido con el siguiente formato en la variable `POST`:

```
"data":{":plan":"Habitaci\u00f3n ejecutiva",":email":"asd@asd.com"}
```

Lo que debería recibir en el backend es:

```
"data":{":plan":"Habitación ejecutiva",":email":"asd@asd.com"}
```

**Esa es la representacion del como llegan los datos al backend y el resultado esperado, por lo tanto no es literalmente lo que se obtiene en el backend (se usa el formato de array y array asociativo en la variable POST para acceder a esos datos de manera tranquila).**

Por alguna razon, al ejecutar la consulta de `update`, falla cuando la consulta tiene tildes, por lo que se me ocurrio que el problema del que no se ejecute la consulta de manera satisfactoria tambien tiene que ver con la codificacion, cuando no tiene tildes funciona.

Este es el codigo del frontend que realiza la conexion y se encarga de las operaciones `CRUD`:

```
package hotelh_m;

import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Map;

public class CRUD {

    public static final String serverURL = "http://localhost/hotelH_M/";
    public static final String createURL = CRUD.serverURL + "create.php";
    public static final String readURL = CRUD.serverURL + "read.php";
    public static final String updateURL = CRUD.serverURL + "update.php";
    public static final String deleteURL = CRUD.serverURL + "delete.php";
    public static String currentOperationURL = CRUD.readURL;
    private static int currentTable = 0;

    CRUD(){
    }

    private static void setCurrentOperation(String operation){

        switch(operation.toLowerCase()){

            case "create":
                CRUD.currentOperationURL = CRUD.createURL;
                break;

            case "read":
                CRUD.currentOperationURL = CRUD.readURL;
                break;

            case "update":
                CRUD.currentOperationURL = CRUD.updateURL;
                break;

            case "delete":
                CRUD.currentOperationURL = CRUD.deleteURL;
                break;

            default:
                CRUD.currentOperationURL = CRUD.serverURL;
                break;

        }

    }

    public static void setCurrentTable(int tableIndex){
        CRUD.currentTable = tableIndex;
    }

    public static JsonElement create(Map<String, Object> params) throws IOException {
        params.put("table", CRUD.currentTable);
        CRUD.setCurrentOperation("create");
        return CRUD.send(params);
    }

    public static JsonElement read(Map<String, Object> params) throws IOException {
        params.put("table", CRUD.currentTable);
        CRUD.setCurrentOperation("read");
        return CRUD.send(params);
    }

    public static JsonElement update(Map<String, Object> params) throws IOException {
        params.put("table", CRUD.currentTable);
        CRUD.setCurrentOperation("update");
        return CRUD.send(params);
    }

    public static JsonElement delete(Map<String, Object> params) throws IOException {
        params.put("table", CRUD.currentTable);
        CRUD.setCurrentOperation("delete");
        return CRUD.send(params);
    }

    private static JsonElement send(Map<String, Object> params) throws IOException {

        URL url = new URL(CRUD.currentOperationURL);
        StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();

        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
            postData.append('&');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()));
            postData.append('=');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()));
        }

        byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        //Open connection and configure the headers to send to the server...
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        //Send data to server...
        DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        outputStream.write(postDataBytes);

        //Receive data of the server in UTF-8...
        Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        String charBuild = "";

        for(int c = in.read(); c != -1; c = in.read())
            charBuild += (char) c;

        System.out.println(charBuild);
        conn.disconnect();
        return new JSON(charBuild).getJsonElement();
    }

}
```

Cabe mencionar que para facilitar un poco las cosas estoy usando la libreria `GSON`.

del lado del backend lo mas relevante a mencionar realmente es decir que tengo definidas estas cabeceras:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

Ya que realmente desde el principio del código en la variable `$_POST` obtengo la data con codificación errónea tal como había mostrado antes.

la base de datos así como todas sus tablas tenían en un inicio la codificación **utf8_spanish2_ci**, la cual luego para probar si se resolvía el problema cambie a **utf8_general_ci**, al igual que sus tablas, pero tampoco funciono...

Acerca del archivo que se encarga de la conexion esta construido de la siguiente manera:

**connection.php**:

```
<?php

    //Función que conectara a la base de datos que necesitemos.
    function conectar($host,$DB,$user,$pass){

        try {

            $conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$DB;charset=utf8",$user,$pass);
            return $conexion;

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $error = $e->getMessage();
            return false;

        }

    }

?>
```

Esto es lo que recibo completo en `Java` desde el backend, por eso se que hay algo que anda mal y falla la consulta:

```
{"status":"failed","msg":"Query failed!","data":{":plan":"Habitaci\u00f3n ejecutiva",":email":"asd@asd.com"}}
```

**Hay alguna forma de lograr que al backend lleguen caracteres UTF-8 y no unicode?**

Notas adicionales:

- Estoy usando windows 10
- Estoy usando netbeans
- Uso una libreria llamada GSON
- Uso xampp

Comment: Como nota: UTF significa : **Unicode** Transformation Format.

Comment: @Xerif me siento un poco tonto ahora xd, no habia indagado nunca que significaba UTF, gracias por la información, es útil saberlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución fue algo realmente sencillo de lo que no me daba cuenta... lo que pasa es que uno de los problemas era que estaba usando un campo con **llave unica** a la cual estaba intentando actualizar al contenido de otro registro que ya contenia ese valor, por lo que por eso la query fallaba.

La solucion fue quitar esa **llave unica**, puesto que pensandolo bien no me era de mucha utilidad, pero al parecer el registro se inserta con la codificacion correcta, por lo que puedo asumir que enrealidad pese a que el string resultado parece tener codificacion **unicode**, en la base de datos es guardado correctamente como **UTF-8**, tenga tildes o no ahora, es extraño puesto que según entiendo a **PHP** le llega como formato **unicode** y no **UTF-8**, incluso lo muestra como **unicode** cuando la respuesta me llega al frontend.